# How to re-partition each line in a file in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, iostream, fork-join

I'm designing a bulk data loader utility that needs to be very fast. The input is one or more files in some format, containing data to be loaded to a high-performance, distributed system.  To keep it simple, let’s assume there’s one file, but the idea should be easily generalized to multiple input files on multiple disks.

We know that hard disks are serial devices and can only achieve max performance when doing sequential IOs. The backend distributed system is much more powerful and can allow me to load data from multiple disks at the same time.

My idea is like this:

1. I have one producer thread per file which reads LARGE blocks, parses the block to identify individual records, and then "re-partition and send" each record to its associated in-memory container. The re-partition will be based on one or more attributes of each record (think of re-partition based on the ID of each person).
2. There are multiple in-memory containers holding the intermediate records. Each container is bounded to a consumer thread, that fetches a record from its container at one time, load it into the backend system.

My question is:

- How to design a function to "re-partition and send" each record to its associated in-memory container?
- What if each consumer thread SORTs a batch of records in its container, and then loads them in one call? What would be a good data structure for the in-memory container?

Please share your expertise. If you could elaborate and provide some pseudo code, that will be even awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Lacking any evidence to the contrary, assume standard collections will do just fine for the task. Write it, then evaluate performance. *Then* decide what needs improvement, if any.

Answer (score 1):

That is very much like a [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) task. If you can install Hadoop-like infrastructure to your distributed system, this should be easily done.

Comment: Yes, this is like a typical MapReduce task. However, I'm not sure if the reduce step can start when the map step is still running. The other reason is that a Hadoop-like infrastructure may be too heavy for this case. Do you know of any light-weight MapReduce frameworks that can run in-memory on the client machine?